# How to create a new joint layer from two separate layers containing different categories and lat/long coor points, and produce a .csv file from it

Tags: arcgis, arcmap

I have two layers in ArcMap. One contains flooding areas in a city, categorized by nuisance flooding (objectid 1 and represented by color yellow)  and deep flooding (objectid 2 and represented by color purple). I also have another layer, containing street flooding complaints from residents in a given year (represented by the green box symbol, and utilizes lat/long coord from a .csv file). I want to create a new layer that only highlights the areas on the map that are deep flooding AND has flooding complaint(s) within the deep (purple) flooding area. Flooding complaints within nuisance (yellow) flooding or unshaded areas are to be excluded from this layer. Below is a screenshot of my current map:
[Flooding Area & Complaints Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIJrD.jpg)
In addition to that, I also want to create a .csv file that contains all areas that satisfy this condition, and returns the address (intersection, street name, etc.) of each location. I am not able to attempt this, however, because of the prior issue.

I attempted the Join and relate data option when selecting a layer. Specifically, the "Join data from another layer based on spatial location". However, when trying this, I was met with an error stating: "Source table must have an objectID column to perform a join by location". I think this is the option I want, although I am not sure if I'm choosing the right sub options or the files I've provided can satisfy the requirements to perform this operation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use "Spatial Join" instead of "Join".

Tool parameters is going to be like this:

Target Features: Select your flooding areas layer (the one with yellow and purple areas).

Join Features: Select your flooding complaints layer (the one with green boxes).

Output Feature Class: Choose a location and name for the output layer.

Join Operation: Choose "Join one to one" (this ensures that each complaint is matched to a specific flooding area).

Match Option: Choose "WITHIN".

Search Radius: Leave this blank or set it to a small value if you want to capture complaints that are very close to but not within the flooding areas.

Field Mapping: You want to keep only those complaints that fall within the purple (deep flooding) areas. So, under the "Field Map of Join Features"
section, select the green box complaint symbol and remove it by right-clicking and choosing "Remove".

Merge Rule: Set this to "Join" for the deep flooding area (purple) feature class.

This will create a new layer that contains only the deep flooding areas with corresponding complaints within those areas.